# How to get files change of a given branch?

Tags: branch, commit, gitpython

I struggle to find how to get the list of files that have been modified on my current branch (and ONLY on my current branch, not on the other branches).

For example, I have a branch `my_branch` based on the branch `develop_branch`. I have done a git rebase of `my_branch` up to `develop_branch`. So when I do git log I have something like that :

| branch name | commits |
| --- | --- |
| my_branch | HEAD |
| my_branch | HEAD~1 |
| my_branch | HEAD~2 |
| develop_branch | HEAD~3 |
| develop_branch | HEAD~4 |
| ... | ... |

Important: the number of commits in `my_branch` is not fixed.

How do I get the files changed only on my_branch? (so in the example only from `HEAD` to `HEAD\~2`)

What I have done up to now:

```
repo = Repo('My_Repo')
hcommit = repo.head.commit
diff_previous = hcommit.diff("**HEAD~???**")
for diff_added in diff_previous:
    print(diff_added)
```

But I don't know how to get the good `HEAD-???`, corresponding to the first commit of `my_branch`.

Do someone know and can help me, please?

PS: the documentation of [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) doesn't help me, and doesn't detail all possible methods for the repo.